# React not passing along properties when rendering in variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a reusable component for menu itens, but React is not passing along the properties to the HTML when I render it in a variable.
I'm using Browserify with the reactify tranform.

Here is the component code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;



var Menu = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    route: React.PropTypes.string,
    key: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },

  render: function() {
    //alert(this.props.route);
    var routeName = this.props.route;
    var content = null;
    if (routeName) {
        content = (<a href="{routeName}">
                      {this.props.children}
                   </a>);
    } else {
        content = (<a>{this.props.children}</a>);
    }
    return (<li key="{this.props.key}">{content}</li>);
  }

});


module.exports = Menu;
```

The final HTML output is:

```
<li data-reactid=".0.0.2.0.$home">
    <a href="{routeName}" data reactid=".0.0.2.0.$home.0">Home</a>
</li>
```

The key property is function properly, but the route property is not (the value is correct, but it is not rendering the way it should).

If I change the render method to:

```
render: function() {
    //alert(this.props.route);
    var routeName = this.props.route;
    var content = null;
    if (routeName) {
        return (<li key="{this.props.key}">
                    <a href={routeName}>{this.props.children}</a>
                </li>)
    } else {
        return (<li key="{this.props.key}">
                    <a>{this.props.children}</a>
                </li>)
    }

}
```

Now it works. Can anyone point me to why is this?

Comment: Why are you quoting the values? You should be able to do `href={ routeName }` for example.

Comment: That's it, that was the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @WiredPrairie Make an answer out of your comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to drop the quotes when you set properties on the sub-components:

```
<a href={ routeName }>{ label}</a>
```

They'll be properly quoted by the React rendering process.

Comment: How to add hash with href?

Comment: @Sorter - just add it to the string. I'm not sure what you're asking if that's not the answer.