# How to add hash symbol for href attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<a href={ routeName }>{ label}</a>
```

Reference: [React not passing along properties when rendering in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810794/react-not-passing-along-properties-when-rendering-in-variable)

I've tried

```
<a href={# routeName }>{ label}</a>

<a href=#{ routeName }>{ label}</a>
```

Both give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <a href={ ('#' + this.props.routeName) }>{ this.props.routeName }</a>;
```

also you can omit `()`

```
   <a href={ '#' + this.props.routeName }>{ this.props.routeName }</a>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/17235/)

Answer (score 0):

I can define a variable and prepend the hash symbol.

```
var link = '#' + this.props.routeName;
<a href={link}>{ label}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ES6 Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
<a href={ `#${routeName}` }>{label}</a>
```